# accessing array with pointer of int declared before it

Tags: arrays, c, shell, pointers

how is it if i declare an integer folllowed by an array as such

```
int n;
int a[5];
int *p = &n;
```

then declare a pointer for n, the pointer for a[0] is apparently equal to (p + 3) yet I thought an int takes 4bytes of space. And also on viewing the specific addresses there's 4 for n  20 for a and 2 that i can't identify inbetween.

Personally I thought am to just do `*(p + 4)` to access the array value

Comment: Why you have decided that " the pointer for a[0] is apparently equal to (p + 3)"?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic does not (necessarily) operate in units of bytes, but rather in units the size of the pointed-to type.  But in any case, it is erroneous to try to use the address of your `n` to derive a pointer to anything outside `n`.